# Suggested edits icon is difficult to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It looked right initially, but now the suggested edits indicator looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the suggested edits icon]

<sub>(there's a "1" in there if you squint hard)</sub>

Comment: i'm looking into this.

Comment: @Jin The same thing also happens with a user's total flagged posts count on their user page (e.g. [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73/michael-mrozek))

Comment: the fix will be in the next deployment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix will be in the next build.